# Is there a use for every item in Skyrim?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Can every item in Skyrim be used for something? I find a lot of objects like ruined books, embalming tools, etc. that I haven't found a use for yet.

Comment: Buckets, although seemingly useless, can be used to [humanely blind people](http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=skyrim%20buckets&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCAQtwIwAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DccBQZVpVvAE&ei=eGPPTqPYGciG8gPnxeX8Dw&usg=AFQjCNF-C4VebeWkGtZRUB9C8MKqnpm8zg&sig2=JEMdwTk7sbi847wloTu7AA).

Comment: In the next update Bethesda will remove that "feature".

Comment: @Xenox: can you quote a source for that?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Some items that seem useless at first do have a hidden use.

> For example, ruined books can be used to create [summon Atronach spell tomes](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Atronach_Forge)

Comment: Darn I wish I hadn't dumped those then...

Answer (score 35):

If you can pick it up, you probably need it.

> [image: Thulsa Broom]
>   —  Holkins, Jerry; Krahulik, Mike (November 14, 2011). ["Thulsa Broom"](http://penny-arcade.com/comic/2011/11/14). *Penny Arcade*.

But seriously? Unless it has no interesting value, leave them be. You'll get one when you need one.

Comment: Ahahah, I immediately thought of this comic as well when I saw the question.

Comment: The worst thing is that you have to check every chest, urn and body to **see** if there's anything worth taking...

Comment: At least you can now see whether a container is empty or not before opening - a bit unrealistic, but it helps. Maybe the next game shows total container contents value? :)

Comment: Maybe someone will mod in a broom dungeon?

Comment: This comic [was lifted from Penny Arcade](http://penny-arcade.com/comic/2011/11/14) without any attribution, and the answer appears to completely miss the point of the question. I created [a meta-discussion question](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/q/3717/3389) to understand why this keeps getting up-voted and isn't just deleted.

Comment: "Unless it has no interesting value" doesn't make any sense.  Should that be "Unless it is valuable"?  If so, then I think your last sentence is correct.  Although it contradicts your first sentence, which should probably be removed.

Answer (score 12):

Once you learn [Telekenesis](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Telekinesis_(Skyrim)) you can 'use' all objects as projectiles.

Comment: does that actually damage mobs?

Comment: Lol, mobs. I'm not sure I haven't learned it yet.

Comment: It does damage monsters as well. But don't expect too much.

Answer (score 7):

Ruined books are used in atronach forge under the winterhold college.

The atronach forge provides a use for that "stupid" broom as well, actually!

Answer (score 6):

To be quite honest, all items have a use... depending on your taste of Medieval living, you can decorate your house with whatever you deem worthy!

Comment: Burned books.. yay

Answer (score 2):

Many of the items are useless or have very limited uses. Everything could certainly be sold to merchants or used to decorate homes. However, beyond that, the following list of things have no use

- Basket
- Bellows
- Bloody Rags
- Bowl
- Bucket
- Burned Book
- Candlestick
- Cast Iron Pot
- Clothes Iron
- Cup
- Drum
- Embalming Tool
- Empty Skooma Bottle
- Flagon
- Flower Basket
- Flute
- Fork (non-weapon)
- Goblet
- Hammer
- Inkwell
- Jug
- Kettle
- Key to Wintersand Manor
- Knife (non-weapon)
- Lantern
- Linen Wrap
- Lute
- Pitchfork
- Plate
- Platter
- Pot
- Quill
- Saw
- Shovel
- Silver Candlestick
- Soul Gem Fragment
- Spigot
- Spoon
- Tankard
- Tongs
- Torture Tools
- Troll Skull (Now actually can be used to build a trophy in your homestead)
- Wooden Bowl
- Wooden Ladle
- Wooden Plates

http://skyrim.gamepedia.com/Useless_Items

As have been noted by the other answers/comments, all of these items could be used with telekinesis to create a projectile. Furthermore, buckets could be used to cover shopkeeper's heads, allowing you to steal with impunity.

Beyond these items, many other items have very limited uses and are in general not worth picking up. These include ruined books and brooms.

Most things labeled "clutter" would fall under the above two categories. These items are in general not worth picking up. If you ever find that you have a need for them, they are also easy to find.

Comment: +1, would be better to copy over the list and cite where it came from

Comment: Hmm, let me try that.

Comment: There we go. That's to get around being accused of a "link-only" answer.